# Convergence of sequence of vectors in $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, c-star-algebras

Let $B$ is $C^*$-algebra and $x_i \in B$ - linear independent vector system, $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$ such that:
$$\|x_i\| = 1$$
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \|\sum_{k=1}^N \alpha_k x_k\| = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \alpha_k = C < \infty$$
is it true, that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_k$ converge?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum |\alpha_k|<\infty$?

Comment: And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Proof_that_any_absolutely_convergent_series_in_a_Banach_space_is_convergent) will be useful.

Comment: No, I dont mean that.

Comment: But $\alpha_k$ are complex, what does $\sum \alpha_k <\infty$ mean?

Comment: Conditional convergence - convergence of partial sums.